# Laravel 4 Email : I can't get emails

Tags: php, email, laravel-4

i have written this code for sending emails

```
Route::post('contact', function(){

$inputs = Input::all();


$rules = array(
   'email' => 'required|email',
   'name' => 'required|min:2',
   'message' => 'required',
   'recaptcha_response_field' => 'required|recaptcha',

  );

$validator = Validator::make($inputs, $rules);
```

if($validator->passes()){

```
$fromEmail = Input::get('email');
$fromName = Input::get('name');
$subject = Input::get('subject');
$data = array('message' => Input::get('message'));

$toEmail = 'info@danielchikaka.com';
$toName = 'Daniel Chikaka';

Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($toEmail, $toName, $fromEmail, $fromName, $subject){
    $message->to($toEmail, $toName)->from($fromEmail, $fromName)->subject($subject);
});

return Redirect::to('/');
```

}

```
return Redirect::to('/#contact')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
```

});

and my view emails.contact is

```
<html>
<body>
    <p><b>Email From:</b> {{$fromName}} of {{$fromEmail}}</p>
    <p><b>Subject:</b> {{$subject}}</p>
    <b> Message:</b> <br>
</html>        {{$data}}
</body>
```

but whenever i send email all i get is :

```
Email From:{{$fromName}} of {{$fromEmail}}
        Subject: {{$subject}}
         Message:
        {{$data}
```

why my view does not pick up the data from Mail Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your view has the `blade` extension:

```
views/emails/contact.blade.php
```

Comment: my bad! i forgot that. Thanks , but still the problem is there

Answer (score 0):

Your $data array consists of only the variable message. So, in your blade template only {{$message}} will work. Ensure that you are passing all the variables required in your view into the $data array.

```
$data = array(
  'message' => Input::get('message'),
  'fromName' => Input::get('name'),
  'fromEmail'=> Input::get('email')
);
```

Now, in your contact.blade.php you can use them as normal variables {{$formName}}, {{$fromEmail}} etc;

Also, since you are using blade templating, ensure that your view file is having proper extension i.e contact.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution to my problem:

```
$fromEmail = Input::get('email');
$fromName = Input::get('name');
$subject = Input::get('subject');
$data = array('content' => Input::get('message'));

$toEmail = 'info@danielchikaka.com';
$toName = 'Daniel Chikaka';

Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($toEmail, $toName, $fromEmail, $fromName, $subject){
    $message->to($toEmail, $toName)->from($fromEmail, $fromName)->subject($subject);
});
```

and in the view has to be:

```
<html>
<body>
   {{$content}}
</html>       
</body>
```

**Important:** 
Never use {{$message}} in contact view file, according to Taylor Otwell, that is reserved in email view files

Hope this will help someone one day!